# How to emit last window from Esper's ext_timed_batch

Tags: esper

I use `ext_timed_batch` to aggregate batch data into windows. It works, the only problem I have is how to emit the last window after all events are processed. Take this code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EPServiceProvider engine = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider();
    EPRuntime runtime = engine.getEPRuntime();
    final EPStatement stmt = engine.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(
            "select sum(value) as valueSum " +
                    "from MyEvent.win:ext_timed_batch(time, 3 msec, 0)");

    stmt.addListener((newT, oldT) -> Arrays.stream(newT).forEach(
            t -> System.out.println("valueSum=" + t.get("valueSum"))));

    runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(0, 0));
    runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(1, 1));
    runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(2, 2));
    runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(3, 3));
    runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(4, 4));
}
```

MyEvent.java:

```java
public class MyEvent {
    public final long time;
    public final int value;

    public MyEvent(long time, int value) {
        this.time = time;
        this.value = value;
    }
    // ... getters
}
```

Here is the output:

```
valueSum=3
```

The output is just one event, which includes values from events 0, 1 and 2 (sum of which is 3). The aggregate for events 3 & 4 is missing (it would be `valueSum=7`). How to process the remaining events at the end?

#### Things tried

- `engine.getEPAdministrator().stopAllStatements()`
- send a forged event with `Long.MAX_VALUE` timestamp: this works, however I'm embedding the esper engine and want a general purpose solution. I have no knowledge of the query and no means to forge an event.
- use `stmt.safeIterator()`: it's not for this purpose, returns the events from last window, not from the unfinished one.
- send timer event `runtime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(Long.MAX_VALUE))`: no effect. It does not affect `ext_timed_batch`.

#### Workaround

Send forged event with `Long.MAX_VALUE` timestamp:

```
runtime.sendEvent(new MyEvent(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0));
```

This is not a solution in my case, because I'm embedding esper into another app and I have no knowledge of the type of events nor of the query (it could be anything, not necessarily a query with `ext_timed_batch`).

Comment: Did you try engine.getEPAdministrator().stopAllStatements() ? That might flush the output...

Comment: I did now, no help.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use "stmt.safeIterator()" when you are done processing events. The engine doesn't know what the last event is. The other option is to send an artificial "MyLastEvent" event and declare a context with "output when terminated".

Comment: `safeIterator()` doesn't iterate over the residual event. It's a "pull api", probably an alternative to using `stmt.addListener()`. In my example, it prints additional `valueSum=3`

Comment: The statement you have there is fully-aggregated without group by. Iterator will give you the current sum as it needs no events to iterate on.

Comment: Yes, it's an aggregation of all events in a window so I expect to receive single event. But `safeIterator()` apparently doesn't return the "unfinished window", but rather the "last window". I expect it to return `valueSum=7` in my specific sample, not `3`

Comment: Right since current events are not counted or applied to aggregations, its an unfinished batch.  If you do not like to advance time in main engine, you could use isolated service provider and get a separate engine for that statement, in which you can do stuff without affecting any other statement. I would also suggest ingesting the link: http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.0.1/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#view-batchwindows

Comment: I can advance the time in the engine, because I'm using it only for this one statement and I know there will be no more events. But how? I tried `runtime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(Long.MAX_VALUE))`, no effect.